# extending an object with new functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Basically ***Dub*** and ***Dub.socialize*** objects *already* exist as an included library. I'm trying to extend the library with some additional custom functions that I created.

I attempted the following concept below:

```
Dub.socialize = {
    setUID : function(preUID, postUID)
    {
        // .. function code here
    }
}
```

However, I receive the following error "***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'setUID' of undefined***" from my console.

Obviously my knowledge of objects is a bit misled. What would be the proper method of extending this function into the already existing object library?

Comment: which line causing the issue ?

Comment: That error doesn't really seem to fit with an object literal like you have in the snippet. Are you attempting to reassign `setUID`? `Dub.socialize.setUID = ...;`?

Comment: If `Dub.socialize` already exists, you can do `Dub.socialize.setUID = function ()...`

Comment: @NikolaDimitroff - if `Dub.socialize` already exists, he must do it the way you showed, with his code he loses the existing object with all its existing methods/properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution could be

```
Dub.socialize.setUID =  function(preUID, postUID) {};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dub.socialize.prototype.setUID = function(preUID, postUID) {
    ...
};
```

[Object Constructor and prototyping](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/oopjs2.shtml)

**Edit:** Realized you're working with a "static" object. This only works for something that is instantiated, and since you're not making new instances, this doesn't apply.

Comment: Dissdent, I figured it was indeed in relation to "prototyping", however it doesn't seem to fit properly. One should still receive the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'setUID' of undefined".

Comment: Yeah, I realized that the reason this didn't work is because prototyping is for creating instance objects (e.g. `new Dub.socialize()`) rather than attaching to a "static" object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to create the function for declared object means then you have to use "prototype" keyword  for example.

`var Dub = {
    socialize: new Object()
};

Dub.socialize.prototype.setUID =  function(preUID, postUID) {
    // Function Body
};`

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/proto3.shtml